# What is the best practice to close a DropDown on a Link click in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, dom-events

I have the following code: [Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-fermi-8jy3c)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function DropDown({ close }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/" onClick={close}>
          Page 1
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/page2" onClick={close}>
          Page 2
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Dont hide dropdown when clicking me!</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}

function Header() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(prev => !prev)}>Toggle DropDown</button>
      {isOpen && <DropDown close={() => setIsOpen(false)} />}
    </div>
  );
}

function Page1() {
  return <h1>Page 1</h1>;
}

function Page2() {
  return <h1>Page 2</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Page1} />
          <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

How can I implement this without always passing an `close` callback down to every link in my dropdown?

I am trying to implement this with a hook which listens on `mousedown` and checks if it is inside the dropdown and a click on type A but the problem is that then it closes the dropdown before the react redirect to the route.

The click outside I already have covered with a useClickAway hook but I would kind of need a useClickInsideOnLink hook as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have (at least) two options:

- move Header into the pages (due to new pages are rendered, the header is re-initialized). Forked your CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-feather-zpx90)
- let the DropDown handle it's state on it's own, and include the toggle button to the dropdown. See CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-murdock-dq5td)

Another possible way (I don't recommend it as it adds unnecessary complexity to a simple problem) (added by the comments of the asker):

- Actually, a component updates, when props are changed or the state
  changes. To quote react docs: If you want to **“reset” some state when
  a prop changes**, consider either making a component **[fully controlled](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component)**
  or **[fully uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key)** with a key instead. Fully uncontrolled would be
  option 2 then.

  To trigger the change of props, you could connect the Header [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter).
  This way the Header component get's notified when the location (and
  other routing-props) change. Based on that, you could apply updates to the isOpen
  state via the [lifecycleMethod
  componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)
  and compare the previous location.pathname with the current one and set the isOpen back to false if the pathname changed.
  Actually I do not recommend that. But here you go:
  [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-paper-truu6)

Comment: I really like the first option. Can I somehow trigger the re-initialization without moving the Header into the Pages?

Comment: Actually, a component updates, when props are changed or the state changes.
To quote react docs:
If you want to **“reset” some state when a prop changes**, consider either making a component [fully controlled](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component) or [fully uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key) with a key instead.

Fully uncontrolled would be option 2 then.

Comment: To trigger the change of props, you could connect the Header [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter). 
This way the Header component get's notified when the location (and others) changes. Based on that, you could apply updates to the isOpen state via the [lifecycleMethod componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) and compare the previous location.pathname with the current one.
Actually I do not recommend that. But here you go: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-paper-truu6)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an internal component inside your `DropDown` component and use the `close` function by default, also passing the other props via `rest parameter`. Something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function DropDown({ close }) {

  const MyLink = ({...rest}) => {
    return (
      <Link {...rest} onClick={close}>
        Page 1
      </Link>
    )
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <MyLink to="/">
          Page 1
        </MyLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <MyLink to="/page2">
          Page 2
        </MyLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Dont hide dropdown when clicking me!</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}

function Header() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(prev => !prev)}>Toggle DropDown</button>
      {isOpen && <DropDown close={() => setIsOpen(false)} />}
    </div>
  );
}

function Page1() {
  return <h1>Page 1</h1>;
}

function Page2() {
  return <h1>Page 2</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Page1} />
          <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: That is already some improvement thanks. I was wishing to find something where I use a hook and do not pass anything in the DropDown component at all :P

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's too late but if it can't help someone :
You can destrcuture pathname from useLocation() hook, and on every pathname change
you can set isOpen to false in useEffect.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function DropDown({ close }) {

  const MyLink = ({...rest}) => {
    return (
      <Link {...rest}>
        Page 1
      </Link>
    )
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <MyLink to="/">
          Page 1
        </MyLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <MyLink to="/page2">
          Page 2
        </MyLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>Dont hide dropdown when clicking me!</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}

function Header() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  useEffect(() =>{
    setIsOpen(false);
  }, [pathname])

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(prev => !prev)}>Toggle DropDown</button>
      {isOpen && <DropDown close={() => setIsOpen(false)} />}
    </div>
  );
}

function Page1() {
  return <h1>Page 1</h1>;
}

function Page2() {
  return <h1>Page 2</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Page1} />
          <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to subscribe on current location like this:

```
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
  closeHeader();
}, [location]);
```

This one is good I guess ;3